# MapBox stopped working on SquareSpace and Uncaught ReferenceError: mapboxgl is not defined

Tags: javascript, squarespace, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Let me say that the map displays fine by itself when I run locally.

I just starting getting an error when using Mapbox with SquareSpace. This use to work and I cannot figure what is up with this error.

test-share:198 Uncaught ReferenceError: mapboxgl is not defined

You can see
https://www.5gyres.org/test-share

There once was a map there.... How can mapboxgl not be defined?

I am calling

Someone responded on GitHub and closed the ticket...

jfirebaugh

mapbox-gl.js includes a UMD, and define and define.amd are present in the global environment of your page, so mapbox-gl.js is assuming it should initialize itself via AMD, in which case window.mapboxgl is not set.

This is describing the problem but not a solution. I have tried a few things to initialize mapboxgl to no avail. sort of over my head at this point. Looks like I am getting into the depths of JS prototyping?

Comment: First of all. The question should contain the code to reproduce the problem. Second of all. I perfectly see the map and get no error in the console.

Comment: You probably are seeing the map at the bottom. 

That is not the map I am talking about. 

Simply doing a console.log(mapboxgl.supported()); will give you the error - 

test-share:86 Uncaught ReferenceError: mapboxgl is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (test-share:86). 

The map selector is #map.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually silly as SquareSpace must have updated the framework and how JS files are loaded. It had to do with the MapBox js code not being loading properly. I moved the mapbox-gl.js from the page "code injection" to the site "code injection" field and then it worked.

```
<!--mapbox-->
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.32.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.32.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```